# Authorization in Telerik's MVC extensions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

How's authorization supported in Telerik's MVC extensions ?

I am particularly interested in two cases:

1. tabs
2. grid row editing/deleting/inserting

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC authorization is supported at controller level through the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

The tabstrip should perform security trimming and not show tabs which navigate to action methods which the current user does not have access to.

The grid won't hide the editing/deleting/inserting commands. If unauthorized user tries to perform the operation he would end up with a blank screen (if using server binding) or raise the OnError client side event (for ajax binding scenarios). The error code would be 401 - unauthorized.

Comment: I added authorization to one grid row edit action, and when I press the edit button, Firebug shows that the app has tried to redirect to the login form. I guess I can override that somehow

Comment: I have not tested this to be honest. If you are using Ajax binding the OnError event should be raised I guess and you can act accordingly - redirect to the login page using JavaScript.